# Why can't I replace target string with regular expression in python?

Tags: python

I want to replace the `\n\t+` in the string `"2005-03-08\n\t\t\t\t\t10派3元(含税)\n\t\t\t\t\t"`, why can't I get it to work?

```
str1="2005-03-08\n\t\t\t\t\t10派3元(含税)\n\t\t\t\t\t"
str2=str1.replace("\n\t+","")
str2
'2005-03-08\n\t\t\t\t\t10派3元(含税)\n\t\t\t\t\t'
```

Why I can't get `2005-03-0810派3元(含税)` as the result?

Comment: Why do you expect it to work that way? Because it does in Java? Python is not Java.

Comment: `str.replace` does not do regular expression replacement. If you want regular expressions, you need to import the `re` module and use its functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't doing a regular expression replacement, but rather it tries (unsuccessfully) to use the built in `str.replace` method. That doesn't work, as the semantics are not right.

There are two reasonable fixes:

1. You can stick with string replacement, and simply use the right syntax (but note that this replaces all tabs, not only ones that follow newlines):

   ```
   str2 = str1.replace("\n", "").replace("\t", "")
   ```
2. You can import the `re` module and do your intended replacement:

   ```
   import re
   str2 = re.sub(r"\n\t+", "", str1)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Well your main reason is because `str2` is looking for `'\n\t+'`, which is not found in the statement. And also, your ideal output won't be like that because it is looking for removing *all* of the `\n\t`s, but your `replace()` only looks for the ones that come directly after a `\n`. Try this code:

```
>>> str1="2005-03-08\n\t\t\t\t\t10派3元(含税)\n\t\t\t\t\t"
>>> ideal = "2005-03-0810派3元(含税)" #Just to check if they are the same
>>> str2 = str1.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '')
>>> str2
'2005-03-0810\xe6\xb4\xbe3\xe5\x85\x83(\xe5\x90\xab\xe7\xa8\x8e)' #The encoded statement
>>> print str2
2005-03-0810派3元(含税)
>>> str2==ideal
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
str2 = ''.join(s.strip() for s in str1.splitlines())
```

(although this will also remove leading and trailing spaces).